# ARM Cross Compilation error using fcntl.h : error: 'close' was not declared in this scope

Tags: cross-compiling

I am cross compiling (host: x86 linux) for raspberry pi (ARM) using

```
arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

When I choose g++ it all works out fine and compiles.
But when cross compiling I get:

```
 error: 'close' was not declared in this scope
```

This is the simplified source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;
int fd;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea? Did I forget to include smth? I am using eclipse as IDE.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe it's as simple as this: `close` is declared in `<unistd.h>`, not `<fcntl.h>`. To find out what header file declares a symbol, you should always check the man pages first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>  // problem solved! it compiles!

using namespace std;
int fd;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    close(fd);  // but explicitly closing fd 0 (stdin) is not a good idea anyway
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you look for the man page of a header file? man unistd or man unistd.h returned nothing.

Comment: "To find out what header file declares a symbol, you should always check the man pages." This means "`man close` tells you what header file declares `close`," which answers the OP's question. *You* seem to be asking the *opposite* question: "how do I get a list of every symbol declared in `unistd.h`?" *That* question can be answered via `cat unistd.h`.

Comment: However, I guess I should point out for completeness that [searching "man unistd.h"](http://google.com/?q=man+unistd.h) does indeed give you the answer you're looking for. ;)